Ollama llama 3.1 issue in mac with api call
I have setup Ollama in Mac with OS 14.5 (2.4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9), running llama 3.1 with terminal and asking question work fine. But when using api call its taking more than a minute to get response. Can there be any workaround for this as I see people have face issue with Intel mac's.
